# Heroku: The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I get this error when i try to deploy my app to Heroku. My first deployment works fine before I'm doing `heroku run rake db:reset`.
After this, I have errors below: "We're sorry, but something went wrong." and "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

My heroku logs says:

```
2012-12-08T11:40:54+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap.css isn't precompiled):
2012-12-08T11:40:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-12-08T11:40:54+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-08T11:40:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap", media: "all"%>
```

Some one, Can you help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like Heroku is complaining that your assets are not precompiled. I'd read through [this tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html) about rails on heroku, there is a section dedicated to resource pre-compilation.

You can tell your application to precompile assets in production

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.compile = true
# Heroku also requires this to be false
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=false
```

Or you can precompile your assets using the rake task

```
#before pushing to Heroku and then you can push
rake assets:precompile

#or after you've pushed to heroku
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```