# Ubuntu 14.04 - An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, heroku, sqlite

This issue doesn't let me go ahead and I don't know whether it's possible for me to deploy my Rails App ever on Heroku.

When I try `bundle install` by having `gem 'pg'` in my Gemfile it gives following error.

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

`Make sure that gem install pg -v '0.18.2' succeeds before bundling.`

However, when I try `sudo gem install pg` it says `Successfully installed pg-0.18.2
1 gem installed`

But when I try to run the app locally or deploy on Heroku it gives me the same error again. By using `sqlite3` in development mode, all is well, but the same issue occurs on Heroku because Heroku doesn't support sqlite3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have PostgreSQL installed locally?  If not, that might be the reason for that (having `gem 'pg'` is not enough to install it locally).  You will have to run `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` to install.

You do not need it installed locally to push to Heroku though...as long as you have `gem 'pg'`.  You can do so by setting up a different group in your Gemfile specifically for production.  Something like:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, try this: `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

Comment: Thanks this works, what am I supposed to do in database.yml for deployment on heroku, any other steps?

Comment: Do you have pg gem in your production,  development,  or both?

Comment: I have added the lines suggested by you above in Gemfile and when I `bundle install --without production` as suggested by @Ojash everything goes well. Otherwise bundle install doesn't let me install pg.

Comment: You should be good then.  Do you get any errors when you push to Heroku?

Comment: Also, check out Chapter 3 in the Rails Tutorial.  It starts with creating a new app, setting it up for Postgres, and pushing to Heroku (it's only a few pages long in Section 3.1): https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#cha-static_pages

Comment: Alright, I'm reading that. No errors returned while pushing to heroku, but I can't see the same on https://faizanali.herokuapp.com/ what I see on https://localhost:3000

Comment: They are 2 completely separate databases.  One is stored locally on your machine and accessed when you run `rails s` and the other is stored on Heroku and only accessed when you visit the page on herokuapp.com.

Comment: I understand, I had created no database migrations, at least the welcome page I see locally must be seen on https://faizanali.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: While pushing to Heroku, I get the following warning: `https://faizanali.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Okay, after a little research I come to know that it's asset precompilation issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777310/heroku-the-page-you-were-looking-for-doesnt-exist Would you please modify your answer by adding that as well?

Comment: In Ubuntu, I had to install 'libpq-dev' to resolve the error. i.e. 

'sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev'

Answer (score 0):

first thing is you must include the `pg` gem in production and `sqlite` in development and test environment in gem file

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

then bundle gems excluding the production environment

```
bundle install --without production
```

you could then commit and push on the heroku.

Comment: Thanks this works, what am I supposed to do in database.yml for deployment on heroku, any other steps?

Comment: nothing much, you could just setup database.yml for development and test environment only, production will be taken care by the heroku itself, you dont need to mention anything on the file itself.