# "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" even when it exists in "rake routes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When testing the app in localhost everything works.

But in Heroku it shows the 404 page "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." for some pages, others work fine.

When running "heroku rake routes --app appname" I can see the route there.

Any idea why this happen?

**More details**

Only when visiting /new and /edit in one resource this happens

**Update**
It was a Database probleme, I have some old record that doesn't have a value for some attributes

Comment: Can you post your 'rake routes' output and also the specific link you are trying to hit (with the domain blacked out if sensitive)?

Comment: Nothing special there, all the routes for the case doesn't work i can see /resources/new and when hiting appname.herokuapp.com/resources/new it doesn't work

Comment: Do you use roles? Perhaps you are using a user on Heroku without necessary permissions.

Comment: Do you use appropriate HTTP method? Some routes exist only for GET

Comment: It's a resource created by "generate scaffold", i can get other methods for the same resource (show and index)

Comment: if you run "heroku logs --tail" and then view the page are you getting an error or something that might be wrong with the page?

Comment: Nothing there, it's not an error it return a 404 header

Comment: Please post the code or error trail. It could be as simple as a typo but no one would ever know if we can't see what your code is.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not, i tested in localhost and it works.

Comment: Did you check your assets are precopmiled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777310/heroku-the-page-you-were-looking-for-doesnt-exist?rq=1